# Go: reflect : Call with too few input arguments

Tags: reflection, go

I've stucked with problems of using reflect library. I descided to use it because of many recomendations, but i'm just learning go and some parts are not really easy..

I've got this part of code :

```
 func countDataByName(sourceName string, statData interface{}, filters Filter, chartName string) []ChartElement {
            ...
    //step 1 - filter
    filteredData := reflect.ValueOf(statData).MethodByName("FilterData").Call([]reflect.Value{})

    //step 2 - cluster
    //  clusterData := reflect.ValueOf(filteredData).MethodByName("clusterData").Call([]reflect.Value{})

    //step 3 - count
    //  countedData := reflect.ValueOf(clusterData).MethodByName(chartName).Call([]reflect.Value{})

    fmt.Println("Never prints to anywhere", filteredData)

            ...
     return filterData
 }
```

If I execute the method like this, I get error : `reflect: Call with too few input arguments`. But if I change `reflect.ValueOf(statData)` on `reflect.ValueOf(&statData)` than error is `reflect: call of reflect.Value.Call on zero Value`

`statData` comes with one of 2 types, and fore this types I have structs and methods, like this :

```
type NoaggModel struct {
    Date             string
    Hour             int
    Id_user          int
    Id_line          int
    Id_region        int
    Id_tree_devision int
    N_inb            int
    N_inb_d          int
    T_ring           int
    T_inb            int
    T_inb_d          int
    T_hold           int
    T_acw            int
    T_acw_d          int
    T_wait           int
}

func (ng *NoaggModel) FilterData( data NoaggModel) {
    fmt.Println("FilterData")
    fmt.Println("data : ", data)
}
```

this Println also not works. Code panics above , and method was not triggered. Where is my mistake here?

***Upd 1:***

Found that if I remove param `data` in functioin that I want to call, than it calls nicely. But! 
I have `statData` as 1 row, of structs, so type is `NoaggModel`. And in the method `FilterData` I get this 1 row as `ng`. But I need to change it to the `[]NoaggModel`. How to call `reflect` in this case and how to pass parameter to the filter function ?

***Upd 2:***
I modified few parts :

```
func (ng *NoaggModel) FilterData(filter interface{}, data NoaggModel) {
    fmt.Println("data : ",ng)
}
```

In here, how to pass correct type to `filter`, if it is set up in revel controller, and method is in model. Or should I set the type in each model and call it in controller?

And in controller I wrote :

```
//step 1 - filter
    in := make([]reflect.Value, 2)

    in[0] = reflect.ValueOf(filters)
    in[1] = reflect.ValueOf(statData)

    filteredData := reflect.ValueOf(statData).MethodByName("FilterData").Call(in)
```

`StatData` is a row of type NoaggModel, but I get the error :

```
 reflect: Call using *models.NoaggModel as type models.NoaggModel
```

The type was set also by `reflect` in code above, like this :

```
    ...
    var sourceTypes = map[string]reflect.Type{
        "noagg": reflect.TypeOf(models.NoaggModel{}),
        "oracle": reflect.TypeOf(models.OracleModel{}),
    }
    deserializedData = reflect.New(sourceTypes[sourceName]).Interface()
    ...
    // deserialised becomes statData
```

Comment: If you are new to Go you should not use reflection. Nobody should recommend it, especially not to somebody learning the language. I have no idea what your code tries to do.

Comment: I'm trying to call function, of the my custom interface. I calls it successfully. And found out how to pass params, but gets the error ```reflect: Call using *models.NoaggModel as type models.NoaggModel```. I'll update my questions for details

Comment: `Elem()` help dereferencing pointers inside reflect.Values and might help.

Comment: Don't get what you're trying to do either, but I highly doubt reflection is necessary. Interfaces should do the trick.

Comment: I'm trying to switch between some struct types, and call the methods from the correct interface, according to the incoming string parameter. I have some interfaces for sources of data, and this data has to be filtered and counted in a different ways. So I need to get cache, put it to the struct, and call same methods but from different interfaces. I descided to make a type assertion before calling to cache, so I make a variable of type ```interface{}```, assert type to the one of needed, get cache and try to calling for the methods using reflection. I have names of methods as strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflection is not easy. And should be avoided if possible.

I admit that I did recommend using `reflect` to dynamically create instances of types based on a map, which is really useful when you don't know which types you might have to handle. But in your case you should consider using interfaces.

While I don't really know what you want to achieve, I would suggest starting by creating an interface that all your Models need to implement (modify it to fit your needs):

```
type Model interface {
    FilterData(interface{})
}
```

`NoaggModel` and `OracleModel` would then implement the above interface by defining similar methods like this:

```
func (ng *NoaggModel) FilterData(filter interface{}) {
    fmt.Printf("data: %#v, filter: %#v\n", ng, filter)
}
```

Then, change `deserializedData` (and `statData`) to be of the interface type `Model` instead of `interface{}`. And since you only have two types, you can avoid using reflect by having a switch instead:

```
...
var deserializedData Model

switch sourceName {
case "noagg":
    deserializedData = new(models.NoaggModel)
case "oracle":
    deserializedData = new(models.OracleModel)
}
...
// Marshal the values into deserializedData which now holds an instance of the desired type
...
deserializedData.FilterData("Replace this string with your filter")
```

And it is done without having to import `reflect`!

Comment: That looks very nice and clear. Speaking about amount of types, there are 2 only now. The amount will be growing during the months of usage. other sources of data would be adopted to the app, and the list of this types would grow. At the same time, I'm sure that the list wouldn't be more than 30-40 ..

Comment: Still, if I would rewrite code, to avoid usage of reflect , how can I call methods of interface by string name, that comes as parameter from ```POST```.  Each type (```oracleModel```, ```NoaggModel```) after filtering data has to be counted in different ways. So I planned to make methods for each interface, and call them by name. If not using reflect, I would need to make slice or map of method names, and call them by name from map ?

Comment: @Altenrion You could also use a `switch` for the `methodName`: `switch methodName { case "filterData": deserializedData.FilterData(filter) ... }` . And if not all models implements all methods? Well, then you can create an interface for each of the methods and try to make a [`type assertion`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to check if the model type implements a specific method.

Comment: last time i was talking exactly about source specific methods. For example : OracleModel (countByX, countByY), NoaggMoldel(countByZ, countByS) I want to save centralized manner, to avoid lots of switches, and to have more or less secure code , to avoid runtime errors

Comment: @Altenrion Another attempt at trying to understand :)  What about not having different methods `OracleModel.Count(a X, b Y)` and `NoaggModel.Count(a Z, b S)`, but instead you could have an interface with the method `Count(a interface{}, b interface{}) Result`. Each model's Count method then will handle the assertion of `a` and `b` to type `X`/`Y` or `Z`/`S`?

Comment: =)) you disn't understand the concept. I'll try again. Noagg provide the data, that has 7 fields. A slice, of rows, that have 7 fields in each. And i can count different stats from this 7 integers. OracleModel provides rows of 5 fields, and i can count other stats, not same as those, that i can count from noagg. So methods are just different, and wirks with different structs. Noagg and Oracle models have a few samr fields like 'Date', but other fields are integers and they are totally different. Hope that makes the situation a little bit clearer))

Comment: This way of doing type casting helped a lot, and made code cleaner